# How do i convert a System.__ComObject to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I have a excel add-in project and i using the Excel-DNA nuget package.
I know i can convert `ExcelDNAUtil.Application` to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` like:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using ExcelDna.Integration;

namespace Demo;
public class MyClass
{
    [ExcelFunction]
    public static object MyTestMethod()
    {
        Application app = (Application)ExcelDNAUtil.Application;
        return ExcelError.ExcelErrorNA;
    }
}
```

but i find another funny method to get the Excel Application Com Object:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using ExcelDna.Integration;

namespace Demo;
public class MyClass
{
    [ExcelFunction]
    public static object MyTestMethod()
    {
        Application app = (Application)ExcelDNAUtil.Application;

        // 'a' was not null and 'a.GetType().ToString()' was System.__ComObject
        var a = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        
        bool isEquals = a == app; // true
        isEquals = a.Equals(app); // true
        isEquals = Object.ReferenceEquals(a,app); // true
        return ExcelError.ExcelErrorNA;
    }
}
```

it seems that `a` equals `app`, right? but i get a `System.InvalidCastException` with follow code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using ExcelDna.Integration;

namespace Demo;
public class MyClass
{
    [ExcelFunction]
    public static object MyTestMethod()
    {
        Application app = (Application)ExcelDNAUtil.Application;

        // 'a' was not null and 'a.GetType().ToString()' was System.__ComObject
        var a = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        
        bool isEquals = a == app; // true
        isEquals = a.Equals(app); // true
        isEquals = Object.ReferenceEquals(a,app); // true

        Application app2 = a as Application; // app2 was null
        
        // Raise an exception: System.InvalidCastException
        // Exception Message: Arg_InvalidCastException
        // Exception Source: 1679a18afa8e410f9a539349639aede6 <- seems a random guid
        Application app1 = (Application)a;
        return ExcelError.ExcelErrorNA;
    }
}
```

is that `a` real equals with app? why i can't cast it to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`?

I try to explicit conversion the `System.__ComObject` to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` but i failure.